# Create VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA column

Tags: sql, netbeans, derby

I am trying to create a SQL table in Netbeans 8.0 with one of its columns meant to store a byte[] (so VARBINARY is the type I am looking for). The wizard for the creation of a new table offers me the option of VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA, which should work, but it raises a syntax error when creating the table:

```
    create table "BANK".Accounts
    (
    id NUMERIC not null,
    pin VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA not null,
    primary key(id)
    )
```

The error is due to the presence of the word FOR, so I manually change the statement so that it is

```
    create table "BANK".Accounts
    (
    id NUMERIC not null,
    pin "VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA" not null,
    primary key(id)
    )
```

but now the problem is that the type does not exist. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the manual page for VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/rrefsqlj32714.html

Note the section that says:

> Unlike the case for the CHAR FOR BIT DATA type, there is no default length for a VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA type. The maximum size of the length value is 32,672 bytes.

So the problem is that you haven't specified a length.

If your byte array is, say, 256 bytes long, you could specify

```
pin VARCHAR (256) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL,
```

You might also consider using BLOB if that fits your requirements. You can see all the Derby data types here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/ref/crefsqlj31068.html